# Is it true you can rapidly power cycle wireless routers without damage occuring?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

The power cable wasn't completely inserted to the router when I moved it around, and it must've power cycled 10 times within 5 seconds. Should I be concerned some damage was done and therefore replace the unit?

This router has a power button that pushes in and out.

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to power cycle anything rapidly if it isn't designed for that. However, if the router still works then there is no problem. Just try not to do it again.

Comment: Agree. If it ain't broke, you didn't break it. The main problem with rapid power cycling switching power supplies is that current limiting (often a NTC thermistor somewhere in the supply line) doesn't have time to cool down and 'reset' to a higher resistance. When AC is restored a few hundred milliseconds later the inrush current charging the output filter caps can wreak havoc. I suspect this is more the case with supplies which are loaded at or beyond their rating.

Comment: Oh thanks BobT, the power was being cycled at the DC end of the cable that plugs into the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on power supply, modern power supplies (usually) work on fast switching mode (they transform incoming power to high frequencies, tens or hundreds of kHz, then this signal filtered out to produce direct current). Internal driver regulates duty cycle of high frequency signal depending on output voltage, if you disconnected adapter, energy accumulators in filter (capacitors and/or coils) discharge, so output voltage slowly falls (depends on current), but when you plug AC power again, they are quickly recharged by higher duty cycle of high frequency impulses (switching mode supplies are the reason why you can plug them into the 110/127/220V socket and don't care about it - their input power depends on output power and not by supply (it only have to has higher input voltage than output)).

In fact, there is one more stabilisation system inside the router which includes different power supplies for different parts of electronic board (it's often fast switching mode too).

From both above - I'd better care of not disconnecting cable because of rebooting router.

Answer (score 1):

"should I be concerned some damage was done and therefore replace the unit?"

Probably not. Its worth keeping in mind *if* there's issues but chances are unless there was an actual power *surge* it should be fine. If there was, the magic smoke might have escaped and you should be able to smell it. Power *cycling* itself is less an issue as transient currents (aka, sparking) or some component taking offense to that and exploding.

That said it is a good idea to take a moment and check everything is seated correctly before plugging in. A mis-seated plug might cause overheating and maybe fires.

Comment: Hmm the power adapter is making the highpitched buzzing noise now.

Answer (score -4):

There is no problem power cycling any electronics. They are built for that. When connected to the el net it gets power cycled 50 times a second in Europe and 60 times in the US, all the time.

Comment: You have a very poor understanding of how electricity and electronics work. Hint: The router power supply outputs DC.

Comment: so DC current being not variable always supplies a continuous flow of power, so a quick power loss and gain wouldn't result in additional power being sent on power restoration that could fry the equipment or something?

Comment: @Frank Sixteen , I dont understand what el net is.

Comment: El net is what americans call the grid, 220 V in Europe and 120 V in US.

Comment: Sure power cycling can produce too low DC voldtage so that a chip doesn't work as it should, but this doesn't hurt a chip or anything else on a pdb. To protect against too low voltage a regulator is used, typically in combination with the charger. On top of that µC have a watchdot connected to it resetting the µC if the voltage is too low. This is done to prevent the µC from producing unpredictable results and hang. They are also protected against voltage spikes by rapid capacitors.